# verbatim environment does not work with powerdot

Tags: verbatim, powerdot

I'm trying to include a verbatim environment in a powerdot slide as follows, but that does not work:

```
\documentclass{powerdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{title of the slide}  
\begin{itemize}
\item  \begin{verbatim}
           abcdefghijklmnop...
       \end{verbatim}
\end{itemize}
\end{slide} 

\end{document}
```

I get the following message in the log :

```
! Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `method=direct` or `method=file` for slides containing verbatim material (see Section **6.4 Verbatim on slides** of the `powerdot` documentation):

```
\documentclass{powerdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}[method=direct]{title of the slide}  
\begin{itemize}
\item  \begin{verbatim}
           abcdefghijklmnop...
       \end{verbatim}
\end{itemize}
\end{slide} 

\end{document}
```