# Powerdot breaks with both minted and verbments

Tags: minted, powerdot, verbments

I am sure I am not the only one trying to put some computer code onto my slides. When it comes to LaTeX presentation class my choice as a long time **PostScript/PSTricks**  user is of course [Powerdot](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/powerdot?lang=en). When it comes to syntax highlighting I really like **minted** not at least because I am heavy Python user. Recently I also discovered **verbments** which is maintained by a guy from my late mother's hometown so I gave it a try.  I really like **verbments** and maintainer's  explanation for what problems he was trying to solve with  **verbments** sound very plausible. However both  **verbments** and **minted** break Powerdot. This is MWE with **verbments**  and **Powerdot**.

```
\documentclass[style=husky]{powerdot}
%\pdsetup{
%palette=red
%}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
linkcolor=darkblue,
filecolor=darkgreen,
urlcolor=darkred,
citecolor=darkred}
%\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{verbments}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}



\title{Association Rule Learning}

\author{Predrag Puno\v{s}evac\\
         Auton Lab}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{slide} {Use Cases}

Some text
\begin{pyglist}[language=python]
import numpy as np
def boring(args = None):
    pass
\end{pyglist}

\end{slide}
```

Running latex (it is well known that Powerdot doesn't work with pdflatex command)

```
latex --shell-escape filename.tex
```

I get the following error

```
Runaway argument?
 import numpy as np def boring(args = None): pass \end {pyglist} 
! Paragraph ended before \FV@BeginScanning was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.48 \end{slide}
```

Which looks very similar to the way [minted breaks Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17458/using-minted-to-define-a-new-environment)

Are there any suggestions how to work around this issue? I have managed to import the code essentially by tex-ing it separately and including it into Powerdot as a **eps** image. However quality leaves much to be desired.

Comment: @Gonzalo Median I just came across your answer. I am still investigating if there are any drawbacks. So far it looks like it is working.

Comment: @Gonzalo Median I just checked several borderline cases and it looks solid. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like  **method=direct**  for slides containing the computer code  material (see Section 6.4 Verbatim on slides of the powerdot documentation)
solves my problem. I really got a clue from Gonzalo Medina and [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71181/verbatim-environment-does-not-work-with-powerdot)
to a similar question.